# VS Code version 1.57(May 2021 release) can not detect git SCM

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using VS Code for over two years now. But, with this update (version 1.57, May 2021 release) suddenly my SCM for git disappeared. I am using WSL (Ubuntu on Windows 10 as host). I tried un-installing VS Code and no luck.
It was only after I down graded the version to 1.56 and disabling the auto update to "None", I could move ahead.
Any solution to continue with auto upgrade On? is this a bug in new release?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any bug regarding this issue for VSCode 1.57.

It is not clear if your VSCode is installed on Ubuntu through WSL, or on Windows (and accessing files in the WSL Ubuntu instance).
I have 1.57 (auto updated) on Windows 10, working with Git without issue.

But in both cases:

- make sure the git executable is in your `%PATH%` (or `$PATH` on Ubuntu)
- all plugins are not activated (in case one of them misbehave), using [`--disable-extensions`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions)

See if the issue persists then

Comment: It is not possible to install VS code on Ubuntu running on WSL, it is on Windows and Ubuntu running as remote. But thanks for confirmation though, I will try out the things you mentioned.

Comment: @PawanRatekar Not possible indeed today. But soon: https://github.com/microsoft/wslg.